# Unplugging seat belt sensor Golf 6 plus 2010

Tags: vw, golf, warning-light, seat-belt

I have a Golf 6 plus 2010 and recently the 'no seat belt alert' for the driver has been popping erroneously, usual when there is a bump in the road or a sharp turn. I can't send my car in service just yet. I can however in a few weeks. Some one recommended that I unplug the cable of the seat belt sheath under the chair.

What I want to know is that dangerous? Some one said something about the air bag or the pretensioning of the seat belt. And if there is not any danger could I just let it like that? I don't need it, I always put my seat belt instinctively.

Comment: Check if it is the passenger seat that is causing the issue , plug the passenger's seatbelt while the seat is empty and do a drive test, then do it unplugged if it doesn't happen in the first and happens in the second then the passenger's seat sensor is faulty.

Comment: I'm sure it's the driver's seat. Sometimes it goes on and on util I push my seat belt into the sheath.

Comment: If you unplug it then you'll surely see the warning all of the time though?

Comment: I already unplugged it and it's ok. It does not show the warning for the driver. It works for the passenger though.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever the "someone" is who said it is dangerous is correct. As suspected, seat belts in modern passenger vehicles have pretensioners which, when the airbags are deployed, fire first to tighten and lock the seatbelt in place. This puts the occupant into the correct position and holds them there prior to airbag deployment. This is done to protect the occupant from injuries from the airbag itself. Without the seatbelt connected, should you get into an accident, you'll most likely cause yourself serious harm, not only from the accident, but from the airbags as well.

Comment: If the sensor is not connected, shouldn't the car always see as the seat belt is on (which it will be) since the warning does not go off anymore?

Comment: @mvaculisteanu - I'm not sure that really matters? Maybe it does (probably does)? You asked if it's dangerous to you and it is. If the airbag deploys and you aren't in the correct position, the airbag can kill you or cause you bodily damage. That's the point of my answer.